OpenLayers zoom to WMS result set
I am using GeoServer with a plugin for a NoSQL backend. I am sending the equivalent of a CQL query to select a portion of a dataset and plot in on the map... like thousands of points. My plotting and querying is correct, but from what I understand GeoServer will not provide the bounding box/extent(I don't know which term is correct) for the result set.
What I've done as a work around is select the max(lat), max(lon), min(lat) and min(lon) from the result set. This should give me an area of results.
Using OpenLayers, I want to pan/zoom the map to that bounding box or extent (whichever word is correct). I see there is a Map.getView().fit() command, but I'm not sure what needs to be done to massage the data. My 4 points are in EPSG:4326 so I need to project them to 3857 and then put them into a format that the fit() function will understand.
let original_extent = new ol_extent.boundingExtent(
          [this.extent_obj['min_surface_longitude'],
            this.extent_obj['min_surface_latitude'],
            this.extent_obj['max_surface_longitude'],
            this.extent_obj['max_surface_latitude'],
            ])

let new_extent = ol_proj.transformExtent(original_extent , "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857")
this.map.getView().fit(new_extent)


I have tried the above to no avail.

If you looks at the docs of .boundingExtent method, you can read:

Build an extent that includes all given coordinates.

where parameter coordinates is an array of coordinates, where coordinate is an array [lng, lat]. This means setting your original_extent should look like this:
let original_extent = new ol_extent.boundingExtent([
  [this.extent_obj['min_surface_longitude'], this.extent_obj['min_surface_latitude']],
  [this.extent_obj['max_surface_longitude'], this.extent_obj['max_surface_latitude']]
]);

